# This is about validating user input, i was doing a tutorial and didnt understand why he had defined the below

Tags: python, user-input

Below is the code. What i dont understand is in the Initial part he defined 3 things.
choice, acceptable_range and within_range.

why did he have to define within_range?

```
def user_choice():
    
    #Variables
    
    # Initial 
    choice ='thiscanbeanything'
    acceptable_range = range(0,10)
    within_range = False 
    
    #Two condition to check 
    #Digit or within range = False 
    
    
    
    while choice.isdigit() == False or within_range==False: 
    
    
        choice = input("Please enter a number (0-10): ")
        
        #Digit check
        if choice.isdigit() == False:
            print("sorry that is not a digit!")
    
        #Range check
        if choice.isdigit() == True: 
            if int(choice) in acceptable_range:
                within_range = True 
            else:
                print("sorry, you are out of acceptable range")
                within_range = False 
    
    return int(choice)
```

Comment: Because theres an acceptable range and the author is trying to see if you're within it

Comment: The code is not idiomatic, much more common would be checking conditions at the end of an infinite loop and possibly breaking out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `within_range` wasn't defined, you would never enter in the `while` loop, you need to define it to false first to enter in the loop. Once you're in the loop, this value is defined depending of the `choice` value (with the `input` function)

Comment: "you need it to enter the loop" is about as unhelpful of an explanation as it gets. For example here `foo = True; if foo: print(1)` you "need `foo` to enter the `if`", except that you don't and it's completely useless. You should explain the logical reason behind that variable.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of within_range is to keep the while loop function going if the user did not provide a required condition. In the case where if a value provided does not fall within 0-10 or is a non-digit, it will prompt the user to provide an input again.

Answer (score 0):

if your choice is not in the acceptable range, the loop wants you to enter the number again.
if your choice is in the acceptable range so the loop will be end because in the code `within_range` will be true.
If doesn't use the within_range, the loop will not end.